# Problem with the `pdag2allDags` and `addBgKnowledge` functions on pcalg package

Tags: r, directed-acyclic-graphs, causality

I am starting to use the `pcalg` package, and I am having some doubts regarding the functions `pdag2allDags` and `addBgKnowledge`:

I am using the sample data  `gmG` provided by the package

```
library(pcalg)
library(Rgraphviz)
data("gmG")
df<-gmG$x
suffStat <- list(C = cor(df), n = nrow(df))
fci.fit<-fci(suffStat, indepTest = gaussCItest, p = ncol(df),alpha = 0.01)
plot(fci.fit)
```

I would like to get the all equivalent DAGs. From documentation, it should work using the function `pdag2allDags` (from [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pcalg/versions/2.7-0/topics/pdag2allDags)). We should need just to get the `amat` (*a*djacent *mat*rix) data.

From the specifications on [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pcalg/versions/2.7-0/topics/pdag2allDags), I thought the following should work...

```
plotAllDags <- function(res) {
    require(graph)
    p <- sqrt(ncol(res$dags))
    nDags <- ceiling(sqrt(nrow(res$dags)))
    par(mfrow = c(nDags, nDags))
    for (i in 1:nrow(res$dags)) {
        tmp <- matrix(res$dags[i,],p,p)
        colnames(tmp) <- rownames(tmp) <- res$nodeNms
        plot(as(tmp, "graphNEL"))
    }
}

res1<-pdag2allDags(as(fci.fit,"amat"))
plotAllDags(res1)
```

But, instead, it returns:

> Error in sqrt(ncol(res$dags)) :    non-numeric argument to mathematical function

We see also the `amat` in the `fci'`s object. So, I tried:

```
res2<-pdag2allDags(fci.fit@amat)
plotAllDags(res2)
```

It also returns the same:

> Error in sqrt(ncol(res$dags)) :    non-numeric argument to mathematical function

But if I use the `pc` algorithm, it works:

```
pc.fit<-pc(suffStat, indepTest = gaussCItest, p = ncol(df),alpha = 0.01)
plot(pc.fit)
res0<-pdag2allDags(as(pc.fit,"amat"))
plotAllDags(res0)
```

What is going on? Is not `pdag2allDags` intended to deal with all `amat` objects (pc, fci, rfci, etc.)?
I was not able to find any other `...allDags` function in the documentation. How to get the all equivalent DAGs from the output of the `fci` function?

---

The same happens for the function `addBgKnowledge`. It works for `pc`:

```
pc.amat2<-addBgKnowledge(gInput = pc.fit@graph,x=1,y=2)
plot(pc.amat2)
```

but not for `fci`, even the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pcalg/versions/2.7-1/topics/addBgKnowledge) saying it uses an `amat`

```
fci.amat2<-addBgKnowledge(gInput = as(fci.fit,"amat"),x=1,y=2)
plot(as(t(fci.amat2),"graphNEL"))
```

It delivers:

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument
> 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': argument is not a
> matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should not be an ideal answer, it should have a better way to do it, but as I was not getting any answer, I have made some attempts, and I am sharing how I had circumvented the issue for now...

If we assess the structure, both are indeed dealing with adjacency matrix (amat)... but they are different... the pc output comprises a '`cpdag`' type `amat`, and `fci` output, a '`pag`' type `amat`...

```
as(pc.fit,"amat")
```

we get:

```
Adjacency Matrix 'amat' (8 x 8) of type ‘cpdag’:
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 . 1 . . . . . .
2 1 . 1 . 1 . . .
3 . 1 . . . . . .
4 . . . . . . . .
5 . 1 . . . . . .
6 1 . . . 1 . . .
7 . . . . . 1 . .
8 1 . . . 1 . . .
```

and with

```
as(fci.fit,"amat")
```

we get:

```
Adjacency Matrix 'amat' (8 x 8) of type ‘pag’:
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 . 1 . . . 2 . 2
2 1 . 1 . 1 . . .
3 . 1 . . . . . .
4 . . . . . . . .
5 . 1 . . . 2 . 2
6 3 . . . 3 . 2 .
7 . . . . . 3 . .
8 3 . . . 3 . . .
```

or, with

```
fci.fit@amat
```

we get

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 2
2 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
3 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 2
6 3 0 0 0 3 0 2 0
7 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
8 3 0 0 0 3 0 0 0
```

The `pcalg` documentation on `pdag2allDags` does not explicitly mention that...

- function definition says 'a Given Partially Directed Acyclic Graph (PDAG)'.
- the example shows an '`amat`' defined as matrix of zeros and ones, without any connection to `fci` or `pc` functions

But the solution I found starts with taking the '`pag`' type `amat` and converting it to '`cpdag`'...

Well... the '`pag`' type `amat` indeed is not comprised just by zeroes and ones...
But we now from [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pcalg/versions/2.7-1/topics/amatType):

- 3 means the column is the cause and line the consequence...
- and 2 means the column is the consequence and line is the cause...

so, we replace them creating a new function

```
pag2cpdag<-function(fciAlgo){
  res<-as(fciAlgo,"amat")#a amat type pag
  res[res==3]<-1
  res[res==2]<-0
  return(res)
}
```

So we get with

```
pag2cpdag(fci.fit)
```

the following output:

```
Adjacency Matrix 'amat' (8 x 8) of type ‘pag’:
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 . 1 . . . . . .
2 1 . 1 . 1 . . .
3 . 1 . . . . . .
4 . . . . . . . .
5 . 1 . . . . . .
6 1 . . . 1 . . .
7 . . . . . 1 . .
8 1 . . . 1 . . .
```

I was not able to change the type, but it delivers a matrix in the `cpdag`'s `amat` format. And can be applied to `pdag2allDags`...

```
res1<-pdag2allDags(pag2cpdag(fci.fit))
plotAllDags(res1)
```

to return adequatelly the all equivalent DAGs...

---

But it still does not work for `addBgKnowledge` with objects generated by `fci` even the documentation saying it uses an `amat`

```
fci.amat2<-addBgKnowledge(gInput = pag2cpdag(fci.fit),x=1,y=2)
plot(as(t(fci.amat2),"graphNEL"))
```

it returns:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': no method or default for coercing “amat” to “graphNEL”
```

The output of

```
fci.amat2
```

appears to be ok...

```
Adjacency Matrix 'amat' (8 x 8) of type ‘pag’:
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 . . . . . . . .
2 1 . . . . . . .
3 . 1 . . . . . .
4 . . . . . . . .
5 . 1 . . . . . .
6 1 . . . 1 . . .
7 . . . . . 1 . .
8 1 . . . 1 . . .
```

Looking at example, a simple matrix work for plotting it as `graphNEL`... so, just converting to a simple matrix solves the issue:

```
pc.amat2<-addBgKnowledge(pag2cpdag(fci.fit),x=1,y=2)
class(pc.amat2)<-"matrix"
plot(as(t(pc.amat2),"graphNEL"))
```